# React JSX renders double quotes around element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

In a React component I generate a list of `<option>`s for `<select>`. This is done in `ComponentDidMount()` and stored in local state. This list is then rendered. However, each `<option>` gets enclosed in double quotes, which results in options not being shown on the page. Here's how they look:

[image]

This is an image from browser's dev tools (I had to send a pic because copying it was removing the quotes).
The first two options are hardcoded, the rest come from an array stored in local state and these are being enclosed in double quotes and hence not displayed.

This is how I set up the options array and save it in local state:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setUpWeekly()
  }    

  setUpWeekly() {
    if (this.props.poli) {
      const amountsKeys = Object.keys(this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array)
      const weekly = amountsKeys.map( weeks => {
        let weekOrWeeks
        if (weeks == 1) {
          weekOrWeeks = 'week'
        } else {
          weekOrWeeks = 'weeks'
        }
        return (
          `<option value="${this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array[weeks].amount_to_pay}">` +
          `${weeks} ${weekOrWeeks}` + 
          ` = $${this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array[weeks].amount_to_pay}</option>`
        )
      })
      this.setState(() => ({ weekly }))
    } 
  }
```

...and further down in render() I spread the options array:

```
    <Form.Control as="select" size="lg" onChange={this.onAmountToPayChange}>
      <option value="0">Please select...</option>
      <option value="111">2</option>
      {this.state.weekly !== null && [ ...this.state.weekly ]}
    </Form.Control>
```

I've also tried to use `arr.map()` method to display the options array but it rendered the same result. Trying to remove quotes by `str.replace()` method only removed quotes that I actually need - around `value` attribute.

So, to the question now: **How do I display my select options?**
Please note, I use `react-bootstrap`.
Thank you all who took an interest in solving my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting it directly as a string in your `setUpWeekly()` function, try this:

```
  setUpWeekly() {
    if (this.props.poli) {
      const amountsKeys = Object.keys(this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array)
      const weekly = amountsKeys.map( weeks => {
        let weekOrWeeks
        if (weeks == 1) {
          weekOrWeeks = 'week'
        } else {
          weekOrWeeks = 'weeks'
        }
        return (
          <option value={this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array[weeks].amount_to_pay}>
              {weeks} {weekOrWeeks} = ${this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array[weeks].amount_to_pay}
          </option>
        )
      })
      this.setState(() => ({ weekly }))
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Ha! That easy? I've spent hours... You've made my day, thanks so much! Of course I've had to add `key={index}` in my `map()` function to satisfy React and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning string in your function. You have to return JSX.

```
   return (
     <option value={this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array[weeks].amount_to_pay}> 
       `${weeks} ${weekOrWeeks} = ${this.props.poli.weekly_rates_array[weeks].amount_to_pay}`
     </option>
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Joe Lissner above was first so he gets the tick ;-)

Comment: It's ok budy :)